# Correct schema.org classifcation: Product or service

Tags: microdata

We are providing a service call (in Germany) that ensures that users are constantly in the right electricity, mobile phone and dsl plan. For example, for the electricity category, we aggregate about 12,000 plans from about 1,000 providers. For each plan, there are offers that change by zip code. Hence, we are wondering whether those offers (e.g. an electricity plan) is to be classified as product or service?

Our first assumption was that the [schema.org service classification](https://schema.org/Service) is the way to go. However, the options to correctly describe our offers are rather limited relative to the specifications available for the schema.org product classification (e.g. the plans have a specific start date from which the are available).

Given that we are still rather unfamiliar with the schema.org concept, we'd appreciate a feedback as to which direction to take.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main entity should be [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer).

This allows you to specify the prices and start/end dates.

If you need to specify general data about the offered service/product, you could use the [`itemOffered`](http://schema.org/itemOffered) property, which takes a `Product` as value. That’s fine, I guess, as `Product` is still defined to include both, products *and* services:

> Any offered product or service.